# CSS3 transition with jQuery only working after a pause?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I am trying to add a CSS3 transition with jQuery changing the CSS properties of an style. (I would like to do it with `transform3d` but the properties are dynamic...)

It might be a very stupid thing but I don't know why, if I do an `alert` before the update of CSS properties, the CSS3 transition works well. If not, it doesn't.

I have a jsfiddle here with the example, just comment the `alert` if you want to see what I mean: 
http://jsfiddle.net/7WPT8/1/

The code used to update the CSS is:

```
//topPosition is the dynamic value
$(this).css('top', topPosition+'px');
```

It only works if I use an `alert` before.

Comment: Wow, that is very odd. I've never seen something do that before :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sven is right, it is a timing issue. It can also be avoided by using a minimal timeout to trigger the change of the css property (in case having the flashmessage in the document from the start is not an option) – check http://jsfiddle.net/7WPT8/5/

(I’m using a var `_this` here to pass the jQuery element to the anonymous function via closure – otherwise, it would not know what `$(this)` is because of the separated execution via timeout.)

Comment: Why does it needs a delay btw?

Comment: I noticed it doesn't work as expected when I want to show more than one message. Here's what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/7WPT8/7/. Try now uncommenting the `setTimeout` line. Any solution for it? Thanks!

Comment: Also, why if I do it with jQuery animation it works well without the timeout? `$(this).animate({opacity : 'show', top : topPosition+'px'});`

Answer (score 2):

You're creating the element and directly calling the function `showFlash()` afterwards where you are using the element. There might be a time issue in the sequence, the `alert()` breaks the current sequence and so it works.

To prevent this in a simple way, add your `div` diretly to your content.

http://jsfiddle.net/7WPT8/4/

Comment: I would rather prefer not to do that. That message is generated dynamically and the div since the start would also result in some changes in the code.